# ExtJS comboBox resize list box height after filtering the store

Tags: list, extjs, autocomplete, combobox, resize

I am using a comboBox for autocomplete purposes, and I was wondering how to resize the comboBox's list so that the height of the list matches the current number of values in the list.

For instance, the user types "62" in the box, and the autocomplete functionality makes an ajax call to get the values matching this from the database.  Let's say there are 100 values returned.  The height of the list will be the maxHeight value (300px) since there is more data in the list than can fit, and there will be a scroll bar.  Perfect.

But then the user types a "3" after the "62" ("623"), and so I filter the current store (with 100 values) and remove any values that don't match '623'.  Let's say this leaves us with 4 entries.

The problem is that the list is still expanding to 300px, but only has the 4 values in it.  There is no scrollbar obviously, but I still would like the height to shrink to fit the data, just like it does if I did a fresh pull of data from the database (it works when you load a new store).

I've done the following:

```
qe.combo.list.setHeight(qe.combo.maxHeight)                  
if (this.getStore().getCount() * 20 < qe.combo.list.getHeight()){
    qe.combo.list.setHeight(this.getStore().getCount() * 20)
}
```

which seems to work fine except in one situation.  On any page where the dropdown (picker?) list opens downward from the comboBox, this works great.

But on screens where the comboBox might be located near the bottom of the page (which makes the list open above the comboBox), then changing the height of the list shortens it from the bottom up - meaning if the box was 300px and I shortened it to 80px for the 4 items, the box will correctly be 80px but there will be a 220px gap between the combobox and the list now.  Does that make sense?  Basically, it shortens it the same way that would happen if the list was below the combobox.....it doesn't take into account the fact that the list is above the box.

I'm really at a loss on this one guys.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Ext JS do you use? AFAIK Ext JS work in this manner out of box. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/NYSFN/

Comment: We are using ExtJS 3.4, and upgrading is not an option.

Comment: My example is basing on 3.4, so it should work for you as well.

Comment: The difference between the sample you posted and mine is that yours is using a local store, whereas mine needs to be 'remote'.  We have 10,000 values that can be entered (numbers 0001 to 9999), so loading that whole list up-front is a bit taxing and we would rather not do it.  Instead, I would like to load the store on the user's first keystroke, with only the pertinent data loaded (for instance, if the user types '2', then only the numbers 2000 to 2999 will be loaded).  But after it loads this data, I would like it to filter itself (as if it were local mode) within the values present. Ideas?

Comment: I'd like to add that what I described above was accomplished in the beforeQuery listener, and we got it working correctly as far as functionality goes.  Meaning, the user enters a digit, the store retrieves matching values, and upon subsequent keystrokes the store filtered itself correctly. The problem we are facing is that the list box height does not re-adjust to the amount of data present.  If the list initially has 100 values, the height will be the maxHeight value (300px).  But filtering further so only 5 values remain, the list height remains 300px (which means 15 'blank' values).

Answer (score 0):

Try using config property of combobox.

```
listConfig:{
    maxHeight:  200// number which suits your need for list box height
}
```

This config should take care of your need of dynamic list height on filtering.